# High voltage ⚡ emoji is white on safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, emoji

I use system font on my web, and all icons are colored. ⚡ is not on safari. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it in the text? I need to have it the same in chrome and safari.

I have set the system font like this:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/

```
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

I know I can use `Apple Color Emoji` for colored emojis, but this is not usable for text.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Safari:
[image: safari]

edit: It is the same on StackOverflow, for example this:  is colored in safari.

Comment: Please put your actual code direct into your question rather than referring to another site.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by wrapping emojis by `<span>` and added CSS to that tag `font-family: Apple Color Emoji`